How do I add a new CMake cache entry with CMake Tools' cache editor UI?
In cmake-gui, Add Entry can be used to add CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX. For example:

However, in vs-code, I can not find Add Entry button in CMake Cache Editor. How can I add CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX in CMake Cache Editor so that I can install both Debug/Release in a folder?

Looks like UI editor doesn't support adding entries. You can use Edit CMake Cache (note no (UI)) to open text file which you can edit. And you can request that feature from CMake extension developers, so it will be added in future.

@Yksisarvinen Thanks for your kindly reply. Even I add CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=d in the Edit CMake Cache text, the cmake: configure/cmake build operation would remove  CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=d. Finally, I can not add  CMAKE_DEBUG_POSTFIX=d .  Is there any other solution?

I don't think this feature exists right now in CMake Tools' cache editor UI. I also don't see an issue ticket about it, so you could raise one asking for this.
As an alternative, I'd suggest trying out CMakeUserPresets.json. Then you can create a user preset and set your cache variables there, and when you run CMake configuration again, changes to presets will get picked up. There's also cmake.buildArgs where you could use -D, but that's specific to CMake Tools where as preset are part of CMake's spec.
Note: For the specific use-case you're trying to use CMAKE_<CONFIG>_POSTFIX, for, be careful. It only applies to non-executable targets, and if you have a more complicated build configuration (Ex. with config-dependent file configuration) you're going to need more than that.

Thanks for your kindly reply. I have post an issue in vscode-cmake-tools: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/issues/4123
